# How to use Draper decorator in multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator, draper

I'm using Draper gem for decorators.
I have two similar models, that doing the same, but using different databases.
In my namespaces I have prefix `Clone::`. So, for instance: `Car` and `Clone::Car`.
I already have a decorator `CarDecorator` for `Car` model. All I want is to use this decorator for `Clone::Car` as well, but when I'm trying to apply such code by using inheritance:

```
class Clone::CarDecorator < CarDecorator
end
```

I have an error in my specs:

> Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant `Clone::Car`.

What is the best practice to implement single decorator per multiple models via Drapper gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no answers, so I will post my solution.
It's possible to do this without inheritance and adding additional decorator by adding method `#decorator_class` into "child" class.
So, according to the example above, it will looks like:

```
class CloneCar < ApplicationRecord
  #...

  def self.decorator_class
    CarDecorator
  end

  #...
end
```

So, by such means, `CarDecorator` will be using in the `Car` model and `CloneCar` model as well.